# Formatting a date affecting MIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, ssrs-2008-r2

In my SELECT query I have: `MIN(a.orderdue)` AS 'Oldest order date'

This works in that it brings through the oldest order date, however it brings through a date format like: 2015-06-11 11:30.000

So I amended the SELECT query to:

```
MIN (CONVERT(varchar(17),a.orderdue,103)) AS 'Oldest order date'
```

This brings the date through as 11/06/2015, which is preferable.

But I have noticed that doing this has affected the output: the MIN function no longer returns the first (oldest) date, but a completely different value.

I appreciate this type of question is hard to answer without your being able to run the query yourelf, but obviously my changing the formatting for the date has affected the MIN output. Is there any way I can amend the formatting of the date without this happening?

Thanks

Comment: As soon as you convert the date to a varchar, it is compared as a varchar, whereby the first character is compared, then the second character, so when comparing strings, the string "01/01/2050" would appear after "31/12/1900", since "3 > 1" and that is all that is used for the comparison. So as as been stated in an answer, you first need to get the minimum, then apply the formatting - although in reality formatting is something usually left for the presentation layer, and not handled in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to reply and noted re varchar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to apply the formatting *after* getting the minimum:

```
CONVERT(varchar(17), min(a.orderdue),103)
```